# Como cambio el valor a un select

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, html-select

cambiar el texto de un select y que me muestre el valor del
value, no se si me hice entender...

le dejo como es que me imagino ese codigo

```
<select id="" name="" class="custom-select " onchange="">
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <option value="U023">Unidad</option>
    <option value="UN024">Unidad2</option>
    <option value="UP025">Unidad3</option>
</select>
```

cuando seleccione unidad, unidad2 alguna opción, que me muestre no el texto si no el
value... en el mismo select

es posible amigos, agradezco a todos los que me han apoyado y comentado

Comment: si pones una funcion y la llamas desde el onchange que quieres obtener? el value del el option que elegiste, esto es U023,UN024, etc,  o lo que dice unidad, unidad2, etc?

Comment: gracias por comentar, si deseo mostrar, digamos estos codigos U023, etc. cuando seleccione unidad1...-> me muestre U023... pero en el mismo select, me hago entender

Answer (score 1):

No se realmente que utilidad le daras a esto, me gustaria saberlo, pero aqui tienes:

```js
function cambiaTexto(elemento){
   console.log(elemento)
   if(elemento.value === "") return
   elemento.selectedOptions[0].firstChild.textContent = elemento.value
  }
```

```html
<select id="" name="" class="custom-select " onchange="cambiaTexto(this)">
  <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="U023">Unidad</option>
  <option value="UN024">Unidad2</option>
  <option value="UP025">Unidad3</option>
</select>
```

Fijate lo que te trae el console log, es un objeto con todas las propiedades de `this`, que fue el que disparo el evento `onchange()`, solo tienes que buscar las propiedades que te interesen y cambiar sus valores a gusto. en este caso `elemento.selectedOptions[0].firstChild.textContent` seria la cadena de propiedades hasta llegar al contenido del texto del option y `elemento.value` lo que hay en el value de dicho option.

Comment: oye amigo muchisimas gracias, es preciso lo que buscoo. gracias infinitas

Comment: son cosas que se me ocurren para usar menos código, ya que es muy común usar un input y mostrar el valor en ello.